# discord.py giving role to users when they set there status to something specific

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

here is my code:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    role = client.guilds[0].get_role(853135302754697296)
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in client.get_all_members() if 'specific keyword' in member.activity]

check_activity.start()
```

and here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 37, in check_activity
    role = client.guilds[0].get_role(853135302754697296)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

can i please get some help with this?(not my code either, i just dont know how to get this to work)

Comment: `client.guilds` is returning an empty list, then your trying to index the first item in this empty list `client.guilds[0]`. maybe add an if statement to check that client.guilds is not empty, before trying to  fetch the role.

Comment: didnt work sadly

Answer (score 2):

## You are starting the loop before the bot is ready.

So therefore the bot doesn't have any guilds cached and bot.guilds is just an empty list.
To fix this just move your `check_activity.start()` inside your `on_ready` function **or** add a client.wait_until_ready() at the top of your loop like so:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    role = client.guilds[0].get_role(853135302754697296)
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in client.get_all_members() if 'specific keyword' in member.activity]
```